# JS CANVAS - Circle slows down when reaches to target position

Tags: javascript, canvas, interpolation

I'm trying to make a circle object move to a **ball** position but whenever it is near to the ball position, it slows down no matter where it starts to move. I can't seem to make it move at a constant speed without slowing it down.

I'm using lerp for linear interpolation and using it directly in my move function.

```
function lerp(v0, v1, t) {
    return v0 * (1 - t) + v1 * t;
};

FPS = 60;

function Objects(/*parameters*/){
    this.pos = new Vector2D(x, y);

    this.move = function(x, y){
      this.pos.x = lerp(this.pos.x, x, FPS/1000);
      this.pos.y = lerp(this.pos.y, y, FPS/1000);
    };
};

function update(){
    //Move object to ball position
    SuperObject.move(ball.pos.x, ball.pos.y);
    drawObjects();
    setTimeout(update, 1000/FPS);
};
```

DEMO link: http://codepen.io/knoxgon/pen/EWVyzv

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on jsfiddle?It would be easier to understand

Comment: @Mihai It is uploaded :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. As you set the position by linearly interpolating from the current position to the target, it defines a convergent series.

Lets see a simpler example: Say you have only one dimension, and the circle is originally at `x(0)=10` and the target is at `tx=0`. You define every step by `x(n+1) = lerp(x(n), tx, 0.1) = 0.9 * x(n) + 0.1 * tx = 0.9 * x(n)` (0.9 for simplicity). So the series becomes `x(0) = 10, x(1) = 9, x(2) = 8.1, x(n) = 10 * pow(0.9, n)`, which is a convergent geometric progression, and will never describe a motion at constant speed.

You have to change your equation:

```
move(x, y) {
    let deltax = x - this.pos.x;
    let deltay = y - this.pos.y;
    const deltaLength = Math.sqrt(deltax * deltax + deltay * deltay);
    const speed = 10;
    if (deltaLength > speed) {
        deltax = speed * deltax / deltaLength;
        deltay = speed * deltay / deltaLength;
    }
    this.pos.x += deltax;
    this.pos.y += deltay;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWpRWJ

Comment: Thank you very much @Tamas :) You just helped a wounded warrior! I can't thank you enough ^^

Comment: I'm sorry but shouldn't const deltaLength = Math.sqrt(deltax * deltax + deltay + deltay); instead be const deltaLength = Math.sqrt(deltax * deltax + deltay * deltay); where deltay * deltay instead of addition of the y-axis just like you did with the x -axis?

Comment: Thank you :) One more question if you are available at this moment. Is it also possible to make it work so that, it reaches to target position at a certain time like four second, regardless of its position? I.e. if it is 100 units from the point it should reach there under 4 seconds, or 20 units, it should as well, reach there under 4 seconds? I tried with lerping but didn't help :/ I got different results.

Comment: For that you will have to restructure your code. You have to calculate the speed parameter in the first frame, and continue this animation with that speed in the rest of the frames.

Comment: Thank you :) I'll be back with results!

Comment: Or in this case you can even pin the start and the target points in the first frame, and use simple lerp to interpolate between those two pinned points in the rest of the frames. So there is no need to calculate speed there. Speed approach is better when some physics simulations are in place, like in a game. Lerping between pinned points is good for eyecandy animations.